# Embedding pdf file and printing to printer with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, embed

I'm working on a PHP/MySQL project that prints out multiple contracts with each person's details and at the end of each contract, I would like to also add the contents of a doc/pdf file (like a half-page company brochure). I need the pdf/doc to print within the same page (as part of it) but after the dynamic data, sort of like in an iframe. Any ideas?

Comment: prints? to the screen? to a printer?

Comment: clarification added to title, I need to print to an actual printer

Comment: What hinders you to provide the PDF as a file and the user can then print it? If you need the HTML page printed as well, add it to the PDF. Everything else depends on what the browser can / does differently, so not really practicable (e.g. the iframe).

Comment: When printing out a contract I also want to include a personalised thank you note and a short Company presention. The printing is often done in batches, printing out large numbers of contracts at once. I need the pdf file to be printed after each contract, meaning 1st contract then pdf, 2nd contract, 2nd pdf etc.

Answer (score 1):

Embedding PDFs is flaky at best. I'm using this page's examples as a test: http://pdfobject.com/markup/index.php

In Chrome, it uses its native PDF viewer. Printing the page results in the browser taking a screenshot of the embedded PDF, and subbing that in. The result is poor quality text in the final output, and it's a little unpredictable as well as you have no control over the PDF itself.

In IE9 and Firefox, they use whatever PDF viewer is available -- Adobe Acrobat Pro 9 in my case. These browsers make no effort whatsoever to try and include the PDF when printing, and instead just show a blank square where it should be.